# Which model to use when data comes from a questionaire? 0

Tags: categorical-data, predictive-models, survey

I have a categorical dependent variable and several nominal and ordinal independent variables. These independent variables are questions from a questionaire. But **some** of the questions are only answered by some respondents depending on their responses to previous questions. Also, some questions allow you to select more than one answer. So, because of the complexity of this questionaire (and as a result the independent variables), I was wondering whether you knew which model I should use?

Comment: You could extend a Naive Bayes model pretty naturally in this case, removing a small number of independence assumptions.. Let’s call your dependent variable $Y$. Assume you have a question N that depends on question M. In this case, model $p(M, N | Y)$ as $p(N | M, Y) p(M | Y)$, instead of making these independent. If question N isn’t answered because of M, you simply ignore this term. For multi-select questions, represent each as a separate binary decision.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect model one can recommend at this moment nor any particular moment unless you try several models on your data. R has great Logistic Regression models that you may [try](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ONFqIk3RFg&list=PL5-da3qGB5IBSSCPANhTgrw82ws7w_or9).

When you try several models based on some metric you will find the best model. Usually the **cross validation** is the way to detect which model is the best for your data.

Cross validation is not great just to detect if your model has good predictive capacity for the dependent feature, but also it can help you determine the relation in between independent features.